# Adding a layout in between a listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to add some headers in between list items in a listview. For eg:

My list is :

- Monday
- Tuesday
- Wednesday
- Thursday
- Friday
- Saturday
- Sunday

In my Listview, i want it to be like this:

- Monday
- [An .xml layout]-> Good day
- Tuesday
- Wednesday
- [An .xal layout]-> Weekend is coming
- Thursday
- Friday
- [An .xml layout] -> Yay! Weekend is here
- Saturday
- Sunday

Please help me on how can i add/inflate views in between
Its a custom listview, I have a custom adapter which inflates the listview. The days(Monday, tuesday) card has other elements like ImageView, button, textView etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for headers and I really encourage you to use a **RecyclerView** instead of a **ListView**.

But, creating adapters manually usually takes a lot of boilerplate, so we can use this library to speed up development: https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter

Check those files to see how headers are implemented there:

- app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/app/adapters/StickyHeaderAdapter.java
- app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/app/StickyHeaderSampleActivity.java